# How to continue a failed loop php

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

how do you continue a loop that an iteration has failed but still want the remaining part of the loop to be run.

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

foreach($arr as $val) {
    if($val == 2) {
        throw new \Exception('Value = 2');
    }

    try {
        echo $val;
    }
    catch(\Execption $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

How do i go about this

Comment: You're trying to catch an exception thrown outside your `try` block. [That's not how exceptions work.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: $arr = [1,2,3,4];

    foreach($arr as $val){
        if($val == 2)
            continue;
        echo $val;
    }

Comment: Why do you throw an exception if you want your code to continue running?

Comment: i am not actually throwing the exception manually, i am just trying to recreate a type of situation am in my code, i am sending emails instead, of exceptions, but the emails return error from time to time and i want to be able to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this pattern if want to follow the pattern.

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

foreach($arr as $a) {
    try {
        if ( $a == 2 ) {
            throw new Exception('Exception');
        }

        echo $a.' ';     
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message ';
    }

    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

it will help for not breaking the loop

Result will be as:

```
1 Message 3 4
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than throw an exception you can create a Log

```
Log::error('Array value = ' . $val);
continue;
```

This will record the issue but still allow the processing of the rest of the array

There is more details here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging

Comment: i am not actually throwing the exception manually, i  am just trying to create a type of situation am in

Comment: If you can give us more details about your situation then we might be able to help you more